# How do you group the values of a column and find the maximum value of a group in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Let's say I have a column named *item_type* which contains values such as jeans, trousers, t-shirts etc.

How can I group the count of values of this column and find the maximum value out of the groups?

I am running the below query get the groupings 
`Item.objects.values('item_type').annotate(total = Count('item_type')).order_by('item_type')`

where *Item* is my model name.

However, this returns the grouped lists as a dictionary of lists, but I need the maximum count out of these groupings.

This is what is returned through my HTML template:

```
{'item_type': 'jeans', 'total': 250}
{'item_type': 'shirts', 'total': 350}
{'item_type': 'track-pants', 'total': 502}
{'item_type': 'trousers', 'total': 136}
{'item_type': 'tshirts', 'total': 450}
```

How do I retrieve just this: {'item_type': 'track-pants', 'total': 502}

Further, is there a way to extract the max values as variables? Basically I want the value of the key *item_type* which is *track-pants* and the same for *total* which is *502* in this case.

Comment: Just filter the QuerySet: 
`Item.objects.values('item_type').annotate(total = Count('item_type')).filter(item_type='track-pants').order_by('item_type')`

Comment: @R.García I don't know what the max will be so I cannot simply filter the results. I want to know how to extract the max, no matter what it is.

Comment: Okay so I resorted to writing a custom SQL query: cursor.execute('SELECT max(mycount),item_type FROM (SELECT item_type, COUNT(item_type) mycount FROM recommender_item GROUP BY item_type)') 
This returned a tuple in the form (502, track-pants)
I would appreciate an efficient way to do this for all my columns (e.g color, fit etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the annotated total in **order_by** statement. You can order by count and get the first item, like this:

```
Item.objects.values('item_type').annotate(total = Count('item_type')).order_by('-total')[0]
```

Comment: Ahh, I tried this but I was using total as a variable rather than enclosing it in quotes. Tried this, it works! Thanks.